# jQuery Mobile Reusing a Header and Navigation

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, navigation

I'm new to jQuery Mobile and have having issues understanding reusing a header and general navigation.

So I've created a header which has a menu button on the right. On clicking this menu bar a popup appears with links to other pages:

```
<div data-role="header">
       <h1>Home</h1>
       <a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-a">Menu</a>
           <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu"  data-theme="a" style="top: 22px; right: -12px">
                  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:250px; min-height: 698px;">
                      <li><a href="test1.html">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="test2.html">Second</a></li>
                 </ul>
           </div>
</div>
```

I can duplicate this code across all pages but from what I've briefly read jQuery does that for me automatically. Is this true. If not how do i get it to.

Following from this question when it comes to navigating pages and reusing headers is the `a href` the standard way to do load new pages?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use *External* Header and Popup and have them accessible from any page.

Place both div *separately* inside `body` not inside any other page. Make sure you don't wrap Popup div in any other div/container but `body`.

```
<body>
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
  </div>

  <div data-role="popup">
  </div>

  <div data-role="page">
  </div>
</body>
```

Since both are *External* widgets, you need to *initialize* them manually. Call `.toolbar()` to *initialize* Header, and `.popup()` to *initialize* Popup. If Popup contains other jQM widgets e.g. *listview*, you need to call `.enhanceWithin()` to *initialize* widgets inside Popup. just add the below code in `head`.

```
$(function () {
   $("[data-role=header]").toolbar(); /* initialize header */
   $("[data-role=popup]").popup().enhanceWithin(); /* initialize popup */
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/GtLJe/)**