# Popup not working within jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I'm a touch lost - I have taken a popup example from the jquery demo page as a template...

If I put my popup within the first page, it works - I can call it from within js script to open.

Thus... the following does work

```
    <div data-role="page" class="page" id="Menu">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-title center">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-user ui-btn-icon-notext">&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="#OrderList" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all width150 htitle OrderList">&nbsp;<span class='htitle'>Barserver.com</span>&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-notext">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="MainContent">
        <div id="MenuList"></div>    
    </div>
<div data-role="popup" id="popup" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Delete Page?</h1>
        </div>
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>
        <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">Delete</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

I can dynamically open it via

```
$("#popup").popup("open");
```

However if I move the popup to another (data-role) page within the same document, it does not get displayed, nor errors in console.log. Can anyone steer me forward? The following does NOT work...

```
<div data-role="page" class="page" id="OrderList">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-title text-center">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="#Menu" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-notext Menu">&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="#Menu" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all width150 htitle Menu">&nbsp;<span class='htitle'>Barserver.com</span>&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="#Customer" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-icon-notext">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="OrderListContent" class="productdhtml ui-content"></div>
<div data-role="popup" id="popup" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h1>Delete Page?</h1>
            </div>
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>
            <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">Delete</a>
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
```

To avoid misunderstanding - the first code sample works, the second one does not work (meaning no errors, no modal like dialog box gets displayed).

Why?

*(All help appreciated of course)*

Comment: I did find I had an unclosed div later in the document. I fixed that but it has still not fixed the problem.

Comment: Use external popup, or use unique ID for each popup. I'd go for an external popup(s) http://stackoverflow.com/a/22559428/1771795

Comment: Omar you have been a great help here and the jquery forum but I still have the issue. The popup can be dynamically opened at page init when defined globally, or when defined within the first main page, but any page after that fails to change the GUI or error. I suspect I have some dynamic unbalanced div tags but all inspections there so far fail. I'll have to divide and conquer my code until I find the fault. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: An external popup shouldn't be placed inside any page, it should be placed outside; body (page container) tag should be direct parent. Can you share your complete code?

Comment: I've pushed my code thru W3C and done various checks with web developer tools in firefox. I found one double closing apostraphe within a tag and nothing else out of place. I'm pretty confident issue is not an unbalanced tag.

Comment: I'll recreate a separate smaller page, if I still have problems, I will share that code. It is proving a challenging bug. I have managed to get popups working on all pages, and they open when clicked on a physical link however trying to open the popup programatically ( *$("#mypopuplink").trigger("click")* fails (no change in address bar, gui or console.log), but physically clicking on the link shows the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it (thanks to @Omar for direction). A coded answer is not easy but I will try draft and share in a few days (I'm behind on my work because of trying to fix this problem).

For the purpose of this note, when I say "this failed" I mean *"no popup, no change in address bar, no console error."*

I have a form.  If operator attempted to navigate away, a test should be done to confirm all data was entered. All my a-href tags had page references, and **jquery gives precedence to a-href tags over any other events I had applied**. I had not considered the ramifications of this. The result? Form displayed, incompletely filled, operator selects to navigate elsewhere, popup call starts/ends but "failed" and jquery quickly navigates to the page named in the a-href page.

Solution:
When using popups, do not name pages in a-href tags. Thus, when using popups, avoid

```
<a href='#Page5'>Page 5</a>
```

and instead

```
<a href='#' id='page5'>Page 5</a>
```

and create an event that decides if a popup should be displayed, or if not, that page5 should be navigated to.

I hope that makes sense.