# How can I call a header and footer for all of my jQuery Mobile pages?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

At the minute I am hard coding the header and footer for all of my jQuery Mobile pages. In order to clean the code up, I would like to be able to declare what the header and footer is, before calling it for every page I have. I have seen similar questions on here but some of them are outdated and don't seem to work. Can anyone give me a definitive method that could help me? Thanks!

```
<!-- Page 1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

<!-- Body -->
        <div id="schoolpositions">
            CONTENT IS LOADED IN FIRST SO THAT THE FIXED HEADER AND FOOTER LOAD OVER IT
        </div>

<!-- Header -->
        <div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#page4" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="user">Profile</a>EduSub Teacher
        </div>

<!-- Footer -->
        <div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-id="footer" data-position="fixed"">
            <div data-role="navbar" class="footernavbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="ui-nodisc-icon" id="activeicon" href="#page1" data-icon="schooliconactive">Search</a></li>
                    <li><a class="ui-nodisc-icon" href="#page2" data-icon="plannericon">Planner</a></li>
                    <li><a class="ui-nodisc-icon" href="#page3" data-icon="briefcaseicon">Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Instead of having that chunk of code for the header and footer is there a way I could load it in from one source? Additionally, for the purposes of this project, I would rather use something other than PHP.

Comment: External toolbar. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22559428/1771795

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize Server-Side Includes to call individual header and footer files into your HTML document. Here's a resource that could help you.

https://www.w3.org/Jigsaw/Doc/User/SSI.html

This solution is an alternate method that would give you a similar result without using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google search, I found this:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

Include an import on your page by declaring a :

```
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="/path/to/imports/stuff.html">
</head>
```